# Create conveniently Bold version of Font

Tags: java, fonts, awt

does anyone know whether there any convenient way, a method perhaps that would take a Font instance and return back its bold version?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Font.deriveFont()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28int%29)

```
Font original = getOriginalFont();
Font bold = original.deriveFont(Font.BOLD);
```